# Find and replace combination of normal text and hyperlink display text

Tags: vba, string, replace, ms-word, hyperlink

How do I find strings which are partly inside and outside hyperlinks?

Example:  I want to replace the highlighted string in the following image, with a horizontal line:
[image: StringToReplace]

The normal replace code does not find the string because the underlined part is hyperlink and the rest is not.

```
Sub C___String_ReplaceWithLine_Recorded_NW()

'create and cut a line to put it into the clipboard for replace box
    selection.EndKey Unit:=wdLine
    selection.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard
    selection.MoveRight Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1 'moves to end of line
    selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1 'selects the line
    
    selection.MoveLeft Unit:=wdCharacter, Count:=1, Extend:=wdExtend
    selection.Cut 'cut the line
    selection.TypeBackspace 'remove the CR added when line inserted

'replace the text with the line - NW - NOT FOUND - won't find strings partly hyperlink
    selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    selection.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
    With selection.Find
        .text = "Add a comment ^13" 'WONT FIND IF PART IS HYPERLINK
        .Replacement.text = "^c"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is simply that your macro cannot possibly work. Here's why:

Before you run your macro you select the area of the document you want the find to look in.

You the run the macro and the first thing it does is *change what is selected*.

When the macro reaches `Selection.Find.ClearFormatting` there is literally nothing selected. You can see this quite clearly on your screen as the cursor displays as an insertion point.

This is just one of the many reasons that you should avoid using the `Selection` object when writing code in VBA.

You can solve this by using something similar to the code below:

```
Sub String_ReplaceWithLine()
    
    CreateLineAndMoveToClipboard
    ReplaceHyperlinks "Add a comment"
    With ActiveDocument.Content.Find
        .ClearFormatting
        .Replacement.ClearFormatting
        .Text = "Add a comment ^p"
        .Replacement.Text = "^c"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindStop
        .Format = False
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = False
        .MatchWildcards = False
        .MatchSoundsLike = False
        .MatchAllWordForms = False
        .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    End With
    
End Sub

Sub CreateLineAndMoveToClipboard()
    Dim line As InlineShape
    With ActiveDocument
        Set line = .Characters.Last.InlineShapes.AddHorizontalLineStandard(.Characters.Last)
        line.Range.Cut
        .Characters.Last.Delete
    End With
End Sub

Sub ReplaceHyperlinks(displayText As String)
    Dim index As Long
    With ActiveDocument
    'as you are deleting hyperlinks it is necessary to work backwards through the collection
        For index = .Hyperlinks.Count To 1 Step -1
            With .Hyperlinks(index)
                If .TextToDisplay = displayText Then
                    .Range.Paragraphs(1).Range.Paste
                End If
            End With
        Next index
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @vlp-1 "Hi and thank you. When I ran it, Dim line As InlineShape returns an error "User-defined shape not defined"?" - The code in the answer is only for use in Word.

Comment: @vlp-1 - `ReplaceHyperlinks(displayText As String)` cannot be run separately as it requires  `displayText` to be passed into the argument. You can see how this is done in `String_ReplaceWithLine`. If you read the code you can clearly see that `displayText` is used to look *only* for hyperlinks that match  it.

Comment: Works perfectly.  Thank you!  And thank you for the explanation about the display text argument.